# JQuery Ajax Connection Performance

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, performance

I have a problem with AJAX Response time. When Axaj calls a php file every 5s it provides slow response.

The php file connects to MySQL DB and checks if there is a order. It only grabs 1 row if the status equals to "Pending".

Jquery Script:

```
<script
          src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"
          integrity="sha256-iT6Q9iMJYuQiMWNd9lDyBUStIq/8PuOW33aOqmvFpqI="
          crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#load').hide();
(function poll() {
setTimeout(function() {
    $.ajax({ url: "code/ordercount.php", type: 'POST',async: true,  success: function(data) {
        if(data!=0){
            $('<audio id="chatAudio"><source src="woo.ogg" type="audio/ogg"></audio>').appendTo('body'); $('#chatAudio')[0].play();
                }
       }, dataType: "json", complete: poll });
    }, 5000);
})();
});
</script>
```

I would be pleased if you can share your thoughts.

[You can see that the some calls are over 3000ms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jiy9p.jpg)

Comment: Its safe to assume an Ajax call itself will complete in as short a time as possible, this time is dependent on the network & the time it takes for the PHP to execute & return - that's what you should be investigating.  There is not enough information to offer and advice.

Comment: I have personaly checked all the scripts but couldnt find any bug. The SQL code that runs within the PHP file works fast when I try it on PhpMyAdmin area.

Comment: Please take MySQL out of the loop -- to verify whether or not MySQL is the villain.  That is, have the PHP just return a constant value (without calling mysql).